# How to use MFC dialog class from a static lib in non mfc project?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, static-libraries

what I want to achieve:

I have a big existing project which is non mfc.

I created a static library in which cdialogs are defined.

I already read, that it's possible to use this lib in a non mfc application but I don't know how.

I read a lot about mfc entrypoint and initialization, which happens in afxwinmain(), InitInstance, run(), etc. So, apparently, this stuff is never done in my application.

Can anyone suggest a method to use the cdialogs from my lib in the main application?

Comment: Try putting all the necessary initializations in an exported wrapper procedure inside your MFC lib, call it `void InitMFC()` for example, which you then call from your non-MFC main project. If that's possible (doing the init from inside the static library), then your main project can initialize MFC without really knowing anything about it.

Comment: So, you mean, I should export my own function, initializing the stuff, usually done in afxwinmain(). Is this just an assumption or do you know, it works this way?

Comment: Just an assumption. But it shouldn't be too hard to test it, you can create a sample static library that initalizes MFC, creates a CDialog, and calls its DoModal(), all in an exported function, and a sample non-MFC Win32 project that links against it and calls that function. How do you link MFC against your static lib? Is it linked as DLL, or staticly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption worked so far, thanks to @satuon.

I actually copied the mfc code inside afxwinmain() function into a function in my static lib (in my case, an cwinapp method).

In my main-application I declared the cwinapp object as external. Then, I just call the theApp.InitMFC() and it works.

Example:

```
extern MyCWinApp theApp;
theApp.InitMFC();
```

In my case, theApp is global.